# Flash builder 4 does not show export to native installer option?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, air, flex4

i am using Flash-builder 4 and developed an application to capture screen image and save on desktop.
But when i click the export button , the flex builder shows me the option to export to file only as shown below

http://web.s4spk.com/irfan/exporttest/index.html

I have downloaded latest air sdk and overwrite file in sdk4.0.0 , now air app works but how will it show me the "export to native installer option"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIR 2 came out after Flash Builder 4, as such Flash Builder 4 has no AIR 2 specific features.

I would expect that a future update to include this functionality, as it seems like an obvious request.  But until then you should look into using the command line compiler to creaet your release builds.

Comment: You are right but i have seen such option. i can send you snapshot. 
it was shown in the air native app video tutor at 

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/

means there is a way to add such option in Flash Builder 4.

Comment: Post the snapshot and/or tell us which video it was in and at what time stamp.

Comment: Here is the link
http://web.s4spk.com/irfan/testexport/index.html
the video is mentioned at gotoandlearn site and the name of the video is "AIR 2.0 Native Process - Part 2". 
At the end of this video , you will see the person has the native export option working on FLash builder 4.

Comment: The link is not showing the image and u have to watch the video shown at gotoandlearn and its name is "AIR 2.0 Native Process - Part 2". go to the end of the video and there you will see the native export option in flash buidler 4

Comment: Interesting.  Are you using Flex 4.1?  Have you installed the Flash Builder 4.01 update?  http://insideria.com/2010/07/flex-41-and-flash-builder-401.html